# Generating a random number between 0.5 and 1.5 in bash

Tags: bash, shell, random

I need random numbers to three decimal places like:

```
0.624, 1.035, 0.869, 1.324
```

What I am using is:

```
"0.$(($RANDOM%1000+500))"
```

However, in this case, all the **values less than 1 are correct** (i.e. 0.917,0.917,0.917,0.855), but the **values greater than 1 are incorrect** (i.e 0.1195,0.14340.1434) as I append 0. At the beginning of the random number produced.

Thanks.

Comment: `LC_ALL=C seq 0.5 0.001 1.5 | shuf | head -n 4`?

Comment: Generate a number between 0 and 999.  If the number is >= 500 prepend "0." and if the number is < 500 prepend "1."